# Export blender lights to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I need help to Export Blender Lights to Unity, I created a Material with a light and need use this in Unity, but when I export this lights in .fbx, Unity not recognises this, only recognises the material

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the light objects in blender, you can't export them to Unity. Rather, use Unity's built-in light objects to illuminate your scene.

You could try to bake the lightning information into the texture though, using either Blender or Unity to do so.

Answer (score 1):

So you can not import lights from Blender to Unity or even if there is light information in the object Unity will not process it. There is actually a good reason for that since Unity has its own lighting system which is made with game performance in mind whereas Blender lights are made for aesthetics.

In Short: Use Unity lights!